# numbers question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a Football league , each team gains 3 points for a win , 1 point for a draw and 0 point for a loss. The champion of the league Played 36 games And gained a total of 84 points . Given that the champion does not lose any games , find the number of games that the Champion won.

My workings -

If champion won all games -> $ 108$ points

The difference in total points = $108-84= 24$

From here , I'm aware that I need to find the number of games that the team drawn . I'm not sure how to use the above to find the number of games lost . Can I get help? Thanks !

Comment: If the difference from the maximum number of points is 24, then the champions "lost" 24 points. Each game that draws corresponds to 3-1=2 "lost" points. Hence, 24/2=12 games were draws and thus 36-12=24 games were won.

Comment: you are following a good strategy there - they 'dropped' 24 points - how did that happen?

Comment: they lost ZERO games - it is in the Q - it says they never lost. You are correct what without a count of how many they lost, you cannot do it - you just missed that fact they never lost though

Comment: Games lost ? Or games won?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a standard strategy for this kind of problems, that is, turning them into a system of linear equations.

Suppose $w$ is the number of wins, and $d$ is the number of draws. Then you know that
\begin{cases}
w + d = 36\\
3 w + d = 84\\
\end{cases}
Now solve the system, for instance subtracting the first equation from the second, obtaining $2 w = 84 - 36 = 48$, and then...

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. For every draw (instead of a win, because they do not lose), the team "loses" 2 points compared to the 3 points they would have gained if they won. So in your case, all in all they "lost" 24 points, so they played $24/2=12$ draws and therefore won 24 games.

An alternative solution is the following:

Solve the linear system

$$
3a+b=84  \\
a+b=36
$$
where $a$ stands for the number of wins and $b$ for the number of draws.
This also gives you 24 wins and 12 draws.